# codeigniter uploading image from form

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a field of my form (which is uploading personal picture). So the user selects image from pc and submit the form. I am later on handling all posted data via:

```
$this->input->post()
```

My method for insertion into database is:

```
public function add_user()
    {
        $data = array(
            'membership'=>$this->input->post('membership_type'),
            'fullname'=>$this->input->post('fullname'),
            'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
            'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
            'city'=>$this->input->post('city'));
            'profilepic'=>$this->input->post('profilepic'));

        $this->db->insert('members',$data);

    }
```

Now what I want to insert in the profilepic field is the path to the image on the server. I know am doing it wrong above because this way am inserting the picture posted to profilepic. I need some correction please. Is there a function that can perform upload and return the path? but again how can I associate the upload of picture with upload of user data?

Regards,

EDIT: Tried the code provided below and got this:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Use of undefined constant full_path - assumed 'full_path'
>
> Filename: models/membership_model.php
>
> Line Number: 29
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/xsysdeve/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 438

Comment: Have you considered using CodeIgniter's [File Uploading Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
public function add_user()
    {
         $config['upload_path'] = '/file_path/';
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         $this->upload->do_upload('profilepic');
         $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();

         $image = $data_upload_files[full_path];

        $data = array(
            'membership'=>$this->input->post('membership_type'),
            'fullname'=>$this->input->post('fullname'),
            'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
            'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
            'city'=>$this->input->post('city'));
            'profilepic'=>$image;

        $this->db->insert('members',$data);

    }
```

For more information visit this link: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: One more thing I am unsure about...you have line saying $this->upload->do_upload('profilepic'). Are you sure it shouldnt be $this->input->post('profilepic') instead?

Comment: ensure this your form enctype = "multipart/form-data"

Comment: another thing your profile picture field must look like this: <input type="file" name="profilepic" />

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using 2 CI functions and check for the POST of the textual data as well as the image validation:

```
class SomeForm extends CI_Controller{   

function add_user()  //this function is your form
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('new_form_entry', array('error' => ' ' ));
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}


function add_user_status()  //this function is your form processing
{


    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    //$config['max_size']   = '2000';
    //$config['max_width']  = '340';
    //$config['max_height']  = '190';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        //check for errors with the upload
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('new_form_entry', $error);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        //upload the new image
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $image_name = $upload_data['file_name'];

        if($_POST){

        $data = array(
            'author'=>$_POST['author'],
            'name'=>$_POST['name'],
            'image_thumb'=>'../assets/images/'.$image_name,
            'video'=>$_POST['video'],
            'title'=>$_POST['title'],
            'body'=>$_POST['body'],
            'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

        );

        //insert the new post
        $this->your_database_model_name->insert_entry($data);
        }                   

        redirect(base_url().'SomeForm/index');          
    }
}
```

}